# Infinity times zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, education

Assuming the multiplication property of limits I can do the following:

$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}f(a)f(b)=\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}f(a)\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}f(b)$

Why cannot do this? The second one is obviously wrong, but I am missing something:

$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}\frac{n+1}{n+4}=1$

$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}{n+1}\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}\frac{1}{n+4}=∞*0$

Comment: $\infty \times 0$ is undefined.  The multiplication property cannot be used if either limit fails to exist.

Comment: As $x$ approaches $\infty$, the value of $n$ is unaffected...I think you have some typos.

Comment: You can't do it because it gives you nonsensical answers, precisely in examples such as the one you present.

Comment: You "can" do it, and it leads you nowhere as this product is undefined.

Comment: If both limits are finite and nonzero its okay to do.  Also, yea, you have a terrible use of $\lim$ and using different variables than what your limit is supposedly moving.  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)$ is what you mean to write, and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{x+4}$.  Further, the tag (education) is completely irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(a)f(b)$$

is sloppy, you are sending $x$ to $\infty$, but $x$ doesn't appear later.

---

Similarly, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n+4}=1$$
is not true. The limit is equal to $\frac{n+1}{n+4}$.

---

What you are probably asking is if $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$$

and this property is **true** if both right-hand limits exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\frac1{n+4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n\frac n{n+4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\frac1{1+\dfrac4n}=\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+\dfrac4n}=1\cdot1.$$

Now all terms are defined.

---

You could also use the rule

$$\lim\frac{f}{g}=\frac{\lim f}{\lim g}$$ which holds provided the limits are defined and $g$ doesn't tend to zero.